# Traefik kubernetes crd - proxy external host

Tags: kubernetes, reverse-proxy, traefik

Can traefik act as a reverse proxy for some external endpoint ? Like nginx's proxy path for a specific location.
For example, I'd like to perform transparent reverse-proxying to https://app01.host.com which is in another datacenter

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: backend01-ingressroute-app
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  routes:
  - match: Host(`backend01.host.local`) && PathPrefix(`/app`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
....
```

backend01.host.local/app -> https://app01.host.com ?
But what I need to specify as "services" here to achieve that ?

Answer (score 2):

I found that external name services are per default disabled when using traefik with helm. Note that this has to be set for `kubernetesCRD` and for `kubernetesIngress` seperately. This is not explained well in the documentation: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/#kind-ingressroute

traefik helm values file:

```
...
#
# Configure providers
#
providers:
  kubernetesCRD:
    enabled: true
    allowCrossNamespace: false
    allowExternalNameServices: false # <- This needs to be true
    # ingressClass: traefik-internal
    # labelSelector: environment=production,method=traefik
    namespaces:
      []
      # - "default"

  kubernetesIngress:
    enabled: true
    allowExternalNameServices: false # <- This needs to be true
    # labelSelector: environment=production,method=traefik
    namespaces:
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The traefik documentation on ExternalName services pretty much covers the use case you're looking for

https://docs.traefik.io/routing/providers/kubernetes-crd/

Couldn't get a direct link, so please do a "find in page" for ExternalName

Comment: Thanks, but per k8s docs:

When looking up the host my-service.prod.svc.cluster.local, the cluster DNS Service returns a CNAME record with the value my.database.example.com. Accessing my-service works in the same way as other Services but with the crucial difference that redirection happens at the DNS level rather than via proxying or forwarding. Should you later decide to move your database into your cluster, you can start its Pods, add appropriate selectors or endpoints, and change the Service's type.

So no proxying...